# Single Class To Perform General Site Initialization in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, initialization

So once Spring has scanned and instantiated everything, I would like my webapp to run some code that looks for some items in persistence, if they don't exist, create new items with values from a properties file, then persist them.... just some general initialization.

Currently, I'm using a class that implements ApplicationListener.  It seems this is a normal way to handle this, however it seems to run twice.  I had to add a private boolean and check it in the onApplicationEvent method to make sure the code only runs once:

```
    private boolean initialized = false;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent e) {
            if (initialized){
                return;
            }
            initializeStuff();
            initialized = true;
        }
```

This made me think I might not be doing it the best way.

Does anybody have any recommendations on the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found (assuming you've enabled annotation processing, of course) is to put your initialization in a method that has been annotated with `@javax.annotation.PostConstruct`. That method will only be called after all dependencies of the bean containing the method have been satisfied.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initializeStuff() {
    // ...
}
```

It's probably best to split up any initialization you need so that beans are responsible for defining their own initialization instead of mulching the knowledge together in one grand “initialize the world” method.

(You can enable this sort of thing via XML configuration too, but I find it is simpler to handle this sort of thing via annotations *even when using XML config for everything else*, because calling the initializer is an integral part of the bean.)

Comment: The problem is, I'm not trying to initialize individual classes, I need much more complex code interaction.  I call multiple services which access multiple DAOs, I'm making web service connections, etc.  I need to be sure when I run the initialization code that Spring has everything built and finalized.

Comment: @Bal Then I'd put in a bean that does the calls, and which depends on the other beans. I believe that the dependency order is used to control the order of `@PostConstruct` calls.

Answer (score 0):

It executes twice because, I assume, you have this bean in the `ContextLoaderListener` and also a `DispatcherServlet` both fire a `ContextRefreshedEvent`. The event from the `DispatcherServlet` bubbles up to the parent and as such the `ApplicationListener` is executed twice.

You might want to move this class to the `DispatcherServlet` so that it executes once (event only bubble up not down).

Instead of an `ApplicationListener` make it a `ServletContextListener` which loads after the `ContextLoaderListener`, retrieve the beans from the context using the `WebApplicationUtils`. This is guaranteed to be executed once during application startup.

Or create a class which implements `InitializingBean` or annotate a method with `@PostConstruct` inject the beans and in the method load the data.

Comment: Thanks... I'm using annotations to declare this bean, not XML.  How would I go about ensuring only the dispatcher servlet executes it? Class declaration: @Component
public class Initializer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>

Comment: By adding it to the context which is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.